# Is there a more polite or less vulgar, but still rude, way to say, "Head up his own *ss"?

Tags: expressions

I want to say something like, "We have to be careful not to get our heads too far up our own asses."

The phrase has the following meaning, according to [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/have_one%27s_head_up_one%27s_ass): To be oblivious to the real state of things, from either stupidity or stubbornness.

I want the rudeness and directness of the phrase, just not the vulgar word "ass" in there.  "oblivious" fits well enough, but it's not rude enough or 'abrupt' as the idiom.

Comment: Just replace "head" with "cranium" and "ass" with "anal sphincter," and Bob's your uncle!

Comment: "*...too full of ourselves*."

Comment: *Head up one's arse* seems a tiny less vulgar to this American English speaker.

Comment: ah, the old medical condition of *cranial rectal uppitis*

Comment: We need to be sure we avoid suffering a *cranio-rectal inversion*.

Comment: I have no idea what is "too broad" about this question.  I have an exact phrase, and the phrase has a cuss word in it, and I'm looking for a way to be rude and direct without the cuss word.  Could someone help me out here?   Exactly why is this "too broad"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I appreciate your deference to politeness in communication. Vulgarity communicates only itself.

You could end the phrase with a surprise that would tell the same story and carry the same punch.
 "We have to be careful not to get our heads too far up our own egos."

Synonyms of ego or such ideas will do just as well. One does well to remember there are more horse's asses in the world than horses.

Comment: This is good.  I can put a pause right before the word "ego", so that anyone familiar with the phrase will expect the cuss and then be surprised as you say.  But there will be all the negative connotations associated with "ego" and "ass", which will give exactly the impressions I'm intended which actually adds to meaning more than simple substitution.  This is better than good, it's great.  It would be perfect if "ego" or synonym was more harsh sounding. Also, I can substitute other words besides ego that may be less accurate but more situation appropriate.

Comment: Thank you. Your pause is right where I would have put it for just those reasons.

Answer (score 3):

> We have to make sure we don't get too **up ourselves**.

### [**Be up yourself**](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/be-up-yourself)

(UK slang)​ To think that you are better and more important than other people:
*She's so up herself since she landed this new job, it's unbearable.*

---

Same meaning, no rude words :)

Comment: Thanks for providing the British slang. As an American English speaker, I'd like to encounter more.

Comment: Being "up oneself" is a v good way of saying it. Rude, but not so rude.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it's rude enough, but you could say, "we want to make sure we aren't [thinking/living/working] in a bubble."